# Building: cannot disable ipv6: "unrecognized option"

Tags: compile-vim

My full configure is:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --docdir=/usr/share/doc/vim-8.2.0814-r100 --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/vim-8.2.0814-r100/html --libdir=/usr/lib --with-modified-by=Gentoo-8.2.0814-r100 --with-features=huge --disable-canberra --enable-acl --disable-cscope --enable-gpm --enable-nls --disable-perlinterp --disable-python3interp --without-python3-command --disable-mzschemeinterp --disable-rubyinterp --disable-selinux --disable-tclinterp --disable-terminal --disable-ipv6 --enable-gui=no --disable-darwin --with-x`

It has `--disable-ipv6`. Why this is not legal flag? I see `ipv6` in `:help feature-list`.

Comment: Also, depending on why you're looking to disable IPv6, you might want to look into [patch 1661](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/c6a67c92bcbf4ef09063814af0c65d3e0585ada0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `+ipv6` is indeed an existing and valid Vim feature, it's not directly available for enabling or disabling via an `--enable-*` or `--disable-*` argument to `./configure`. The way this was implemented, the option gets enabled based on the check for the system building Vim having support for the libraries needed to implement the feature.

While there's no explicit option to disable it, it's still possible to do so, by passing the `./configure` script an argument of `vim_cv_ipv6_networking=no` (yes, pass it as an argument.)

This is the name under which this configure check gets cached under, so if that name is defined as either "yes" or "no" then `./configure` will just use that value instead of trying to detect the feature. Passing it as a command-line argument has the effect of overriding the value from a `config.cache` file, or simply providing one if no cache exists. (This is a consistent behavior of autoconf, which is the system used to manage Vim's `./configure` script.)